# Problems with local pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I've done some digging around but cant find the solution. In my code below, when I declare my `float **array` as a global variable my program runs as intended. However I'm attempting to declare it in `main()` and pass it into functions and I'm getting some nasty errors when I try to compile.

Sample run below:

```
lab2.c: In function ‘NumOfVal’:
lab2.c:116: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float’ from type ‘void *’
lab2.c:118: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:119: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:124: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:125: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c: In function ‘calculateSum’:
lab2.c:137: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:140: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c: In function ‘calculateAvg’:
lab2.c:150: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:153: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c: In function ‘findMax’:
lab2.c:162: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:165: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:166: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c: In function ‘findMin’:
lab2.c:174: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:175: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:177: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:178: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c: In function ‘printVal’:
lab2.c:187: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
lab2.c:189: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘float’)
```

Now I realize the errors for my "calculation functions" are all the same and but the first error at line 116 is different. I don't understand why once I declare my pointer locally in `main()`, it gives me all these problems. I have to use pointer arithmetic and don't see how the statement:

```
*(array + index) = malloc();
```

Is no longer valid..
Why does a local declaration change the syntax for allocating memory and reading from/writing to an array??

Code below: Im not including some of the "calculation functions" to save space

```
/* Function declarations */
void printVal();
void userChoice();
void calculateSum();
void calculateAvg();
void findMin();
void findMax();

int main(){

    float **array;
    int numData;

    /*get number of datasets */
    numData = NumOfSet();
    printf("%d\n",numData);
    array = malloc(numData * sizeof(float*));
    if(array != 0){
        /* get # of values per dataset and enter those values */
        NumOfVal(numData, array);
    }
    else{
        printf("Memory Allocation Failed");
    }

    userChoice();
}


void userChoice(){

    int flag = 1;
    int setChoice;
    int opChoice;
    while(1){
        if(flag == 0)
        break;

        printf("Which dataset would you like to perform operations on?: \n");
        scanf("%d", &setChoice);
        printf("Which operation would you like to perform on dataset #%d\n", setChoice);
        printf("1. Calculate sum of all the values\n");
        printf("2. Calculate average of all the values\n");
        printf("3. Find the minimum value\n");
        printf("4. Find the maximum value\n");
        printf("5. Print values in dataset\n");
        printf("6. Exit the program\n");

        scanf("%d", &opChoice);
        /* Switch statement which makes function calls to perform whatever the user specified */
            switch(opChoice){
                case 1:
                    calculateSum(setChoice);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    calculateAvg(setChoice);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    findMin(setChoice);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    findMax(setChoice);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printVal(setChoice);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    flag = 0;
                    printf("Thanks for playing!\n");
                    printf("%d", flag);
            }
        }
}




int NumOfSet(){
    int numData;
    printf("Enter number of Datasets: \n");
    scanf("%d",&numData);
    return(numData);

}


/* for each data set declare size and input float values */
int NumOfVal(int data, float *array){
    int index; /* counters */
    int array_index;
    int copy;
    float size;
    float val;

    for(index = 0; index < data;index++){
        printf("Enter size of dataset %d:\n", index);
        scanf("%f", &size);
        copy = size;
        printf("Size = %d\n", (int) size);
        printf("Array #: %d\n", index);
        /* malloc() for row */
        /* array[index] */
        *(array + index) = malloc(size * sizeof(float));
        /*array[index][0] */
        *(*(array + index) + 0) =  size;
        printf("%f\n", *(*(array + index) + 0));
        /* loop for entering float values */
        for(array_index = 1; array_index <= copy; array_index++){
            printf("Enter each float value:");
            scanf("%f", &val);
            *(*(array + index) + array_index) = val; 
            printf("%f\n", *(*(array + index) + array_index));
            printf("count: %d\n",array_index);
            printf("size: %d\n",copy);

        }

    }

}

void calculateSum(int setChoice, float *array){
    int i;
    int first = *(*(array + setChoice-1) + 0);
    float sum = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= first; i++){
        sum += *(*(array + setChoice-1) + i);
    }
    printf("The sum of the values is: %.3f\n", sum);
}
```

P.S. Of course, when I had declared array as global, I didn't have array as a parameter of those functions.

So it seems if I declare pointer to a pointer to a `float` `float **array` in `main()`. I need to have `float **array` as the parameter of my functions and not just `float *array`.

`**array` --> a pointer which points to a list of `float` arrays(?)

`*array` --> simply a pointer to a single `float` array(?)

correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: you should better read or follow book. do not hurry to do stuffs but  lesson questions. I believe after that you will re-write this entirely and be thankful to me

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you've got to understand what pointers are. A pointer is variable which
stores an address. It may be the address of another variable, it may be the
start of a memory block that you've got from dynamically allocating memory with
`malloc` & friends or the start of an array.

> `*array` --> simply a pointer to a single `float` array(?)

Not necessarily.

Let's take a look at this:

```
float *array;
```

First, forget about the name of the variable, what really is important is the
type of the variable. In this case you've got a pointer to a `float`.
It **may** point to a single float variable

```
float n = 8.7;
float *array = &n;
```

but it also **may** point to the start of a sequence of `float`s (aka array):

```
float na[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
float *array = na;
//or
float *array = na + 2;
```

Which one (pointing to a single object vs pointing to an array of objects) is the
correct one depends on the context. The documentation of the function will tell
you what it is expecting. **That** is what counts, not the variable name. If the
variable name is `array`, it may not be pointing to an array, the name is then
misleading, actually is a poorly chosen name.

> `**array` --> a pointer which points to a list of `float` arrays(?)

Again, not necessarily.

Let's take one step further. A double pointer

```
float **array;
```

is a pointer that points to another pointer of `float`. Once again, forget about
the name of the variable, the context is important. It may point to a pointer
that points to a single variable:

```
float n = 8.7;
float *array = &n;
float **p2arr = &array;
```

or it may point to a pointer that points to the start of an array

```
float na[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
float *array = na;
float **p2arr = &array;

// *p2arr[0] == 1.1
// *(p2arr[0] + 1) == 2.2
// *(p2arr[0] + 2) == 3.3
```

or it may point to an array of pointers that point to a single `float` values:

```
float a=1.1, b=2.2, c=3.3;
float **ppa = calloc(3, sizeof *ppa);

ppa[0] = &a;
ppa[1] = &b;
ppa[2] = &b;
```

or it may point to an array if pointers that point to an array of `float`
values:

```
float **ppa = calloc(3, sizeof *ppa);

ppa[0] = calloc(5, sizeof *ppa[0]);
ppa[1] = calloc(2, sizeof *ppa[1]);
ppa[2] = calloc(9, sizeof *ppa[2]);

ppa[0][0] = 1.1;
ppa[0][1] = 2.2;

ppa[1][0] = 10.8;

ppa[2][5] = 11.1;
```

The context matter, and if you are using a function that has a `float **arg`
argument, the function documentation will tell you what it will expect from such
a pointer. If **you** are creating a function, **you** decide the context,
because you know what you are working with.

So about your code. As far as I can see, `float **array;` in `main` allocates
memory for an array of pointers. I'd suggest in this case to use `calloc`
instead, because `calloc` sets the allocated memory to 0. It makes initializing
and freeing the whole block easier even if subsequent calls of
`malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc` fail.

```
array = calloc(numData, sizeof *array);
```

Also note that I'm not using the `sizeof(float*)` here but instead `sizeof *array`.
The former is not incorrect, but it is easier to make mistakes like forgetting
the `*` or adding more than needed, specially when
dealing with double pointer. The later however will always return the correct
size, regardless of the type.

Now you're array is allocated and initialized. All pointers `array[0]`,
`array[1]`, etc are initialized and point to `NULL`. The you call
`NumOfVal(numData, array);` and that's where all goes wrong.

Let's see the signature of the function:

```
int NumOfVal(int data, float *array);
```

It expects a single pointer, so that's not good, you cannot pass the double
pointer. Since you are writing the function yourself, you can change the
function and set your own context.

Before fixing the function, let's look at this line in `NumOfVal`:

```
*(array + index) = malloc(size * sizeof(float));
```

Again here, I'd suggest using `calloc`. Second let's take look at this:
`*(array + index)`. It is the same as doing `array[index]` and will return you
a `float`. You are essentially doing:

```
float f = malloc(sizeof * sizeof(float));
```

This is just wrong, because `malloc` returns a `void` pointer, you cannot set a
`float` to a `void` pointer.

But also you train of thoughts are wrong here, because the `array` variable in
`main` is a double pointer, the memory layout is different. Why?

I will changed the name of the variable, to make it clear which variable I'm referring to.
`*(array_main + index)` is the same as doing `array_main[index]`. It returns you
a pointer to `float`. When you pass `array_main` to `NumOfVal`, you are now
treating it like a single pointer. The size of a `float` and the size of a
pointer to `float` might not be the same, so `array_main + index` and `array + index` will return you a
different memory location. In fact it will return you a memory location where a
pointer is saved, not where the `float` is saved, so you are destroying the
pointers saved in `array_main`.

```
pfs = sizeof(float*)
fs  = sizeof(float)


real address          base      base+pfs   base+2*pfs base+3*pfs
pointer arithmetic    base      base+1     base+2     base+3
                      +---------+----------+----------+          
                      | float*  | float *  | float *  |
                      +---------+----------+----------+

real address          base        base+fs     base+2*fs   base+3*fs
pointer arithmetic    base        base+1      base+2      base+3
                      +-----------+-----------+-----------+
                      | float     | float     | float     |
                      +-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The graph above shows you the same memory address `base` seen as a
`float**` (top) and seen as a `float*` (bottom). Basically the top representation
is what you have for `array` in `main`. The bottom one is what you have for
`array` in `NumOfVal`. You see the pointer arithmetic doesn't line up and so you
are accessing the incorrect memory locations and that yields undefined
behaviour.

How to fix it? Fix the `NumOfVal` like this:

```
int NumOfVal(int data, float **array) {
    int index; /* counters */
    int array_index;
    int copy;
    float size;
    float val;

    for(index = 0; index < data;index++){
        printf("Enter size of dataset %d:\n", index);
        scanf("%f", &size);
        copy = size;
        printf("Size = %d\n", (int) size);
        printf("Array #: %d\n", index);
        /* malloc() for row */
        /* array[index] */
        array[index] = calloc(size + 1, sizeof *index);
        array[index][0] = size;
```

I see you want to use the first element to save the size. It's a nice strategy,
but you need to allocate one more element because of this, otherwise you `for`
loop will overflow.

You have the same problem in `calculateSum`, same fix:

```
void calculateSum(int setChoice, float **array){
    int i;
    int first = array[setChoice-1][0];
    float sum = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= first; i++){
        sum += array[setChoice - 1][i];
    }
    printf("The sum of the values is: %.3f\n", sum);
}
```

Never forget to check the return value of `malloc` & friends, if they return
`NULL`, you cannot access that memory. Also write a function that frees the
memory. Here `calloc` comes in handy because `free(NULL);` is legal.

```
void free_array(int size, float **array)
{
    if(array == NULL)
        return;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        free(array[i]);

    free(array);
}
```

In your `NumOfVal` function you should do:

```
array[index] = calloc(size + 1, sizeof *index);
if(array[index] == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    return 0;
}
```

Also you are forgetting to return a value in `NumOfVal`. If your function is not
going to return a value anyway, declare it as `void`.

Now in `main` after doing your calculations:

```
free_array(numData, array);
```

to free the memory.

Comment: At first I didn't like how you corrected my grammar :), I'll pay better attention to that when posting questions. But this explanation is great! Awesome answer Pablo

Comment: @Kyle don't take edits personally, that's just how StackOverflow works. If one of them really bothers you, you can always revert it from the edit history. Welcome!